# Stata - Use gr_edit with name()

Tags: memory, graph, plot, save, stata

I am getting into graphics in Stata.  I have currently been using the `gr_edit` command to have code of what I have changed in the graph editor.  Something like this:

```
histogram Car, frequency
gr_edit .plotregion1.plot1.style.editstyle area(shadestyle(color(navy))) editcopy
gr_edit .plotregion1.plot1.style.editstyle area(linestyle(color(navy))) editcopy
gr_edit .plotregion1.plot1._set_type rbarm

graph export ...
```

I want to `combine` this histogram with another histogram.  To do this, I want to store both of them in memory somehow.  The way I have found to do this is to include the `name()` option after the initial graph call.  But I think that if I do this all of the `gr_edit` stuff will not be there.  Is there anyway to use the `name()` function (or something like it) as a standalone function (and not just as an option) in order to store the graph in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumning that you actually need the `gr_edit` lines, this works:

```
sysuse sp500, clear

* first graph
histogram volume, frequency saving(first)

* second graph
histogram volume, frequency

gr_edit .plotregion1.plot1.style.editstyle area(shadestyle(color(navy))) editcopy
gr_edit .plotregion1.plot1.style.editstyle area(linestyle(color(navy))) editcopy 
gr_edit .plotregion1.plot1._set_type rbarm 

graph save second

* combined
graph combine first.gph second.gph

* erase original files
rm first.gph 
rm second.gph
```

See also `help tempfile`.

Comment: Thanks.  It somehow didn't cross my mind to save and then delete.